# Laravel Eloquent ORM One-to-Many Relationship, Select from two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two mySQL tables of an online shop:

**products** (cols: id, etc...)

**pictures** (cols: id, **product_id**, filepath, etc...)

Any **product** of the products-table may have an infinite number of **pictures**!

Therefore, my product-model looks like this:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function pictures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Picture');
    }
}
```

My picture model looks like this:

```
class Picture extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Now, I'am trying to list all products **together** with their corresponding picture datasets. I tried running multiple codes. However, none of the following codes works:

```
\App\Product::pictures()->get()
```

doesn't work! This error is shown:

```
Non-static method App\Product::pictures() should not be called statically
```

I also tried some other methods, e.g.

```
\App\Product::with('pictures')->get());
```

Error:

```
Trying to get property 'filepath' of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/testproject/resources/views/products.blade.php)
```

Remark: Filepath is a column of pictures. I am trying to access it in the blade like this:

```
{{$products->picture->filepath}}
```

I am now working for hours on this tiny thing - but I just don't get it what I am doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two potential issues with what you are doing.

1. You are using `{{$products->picture->filepath}}` so I assume you are doing soething like:

`$products = \App\Product::with('pictures')->get());`

Here `$products` is a collection of `Product` models. The collection does not have a `picture` attribute.

2. You are looping over the products something like

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{$product->picture->filepath}}
@endforeach
```

Unless EVERY product has a picture, this can result in the error you stated. If the product does not have a picture, then you will be calling filepath on null. You can address this in several ways, I will list one below:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @if(!empty($product->picture))
        {{$product->picture->filepath}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

As OP noted in comments below the root issue is that the relationship is has many. So to use pictures you should do:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @foreach($product->pictures as $picture)
        {{$picture->filepath}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! My main problem remains untouched! My goal is to have an array/collection which lists all products with their corresponding pictures! product1=>pic1,pic2,pic3 - product2=> pic4,pic5,pic6... However the pictures don't even get selected from database! I am wondering if I have a mistake in my defintion or understanding of relationships?

Comment: @Chris Will you add ```dd(\App\Product::with('pictures')->get()));``` in your answer please

Comment: Dear Kurt, thank you so much! Your code snippet helped me in finding the problem! Here in the test environment, I was trying to access the first picture like ```$product->picture->filepath```. But! Oh lol... Each product could of course have many pictures! Therefore it is necessary to access them using foreach or some other way - even in case there is only one picture available for this product: ```foreach ($product->picture as $p) { $p->filepath } ``` :D Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Chris Good job, I will update my answer, since I missed the hasMany relationship somehow too.